# Enterprise Target Rule (rule based relation) Widget

Tags: magento-enterprise, targetrule

**Update x 2**:

I have a widget that displays related products in Magento EE, but for whatever reason it only displays the manually related products and not the target rule(rule based) related products. This is the code that performs the action:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/88fac29671bdc31c771e

In app/code/core/Enterprise/TargetRule/Block/Catalog/Product/List/Abstract.php in line 50, I saw it added "Enterprise_TargetRule_Model_Rule::RELATED_PRODUCTS: " to the case as such:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3323e4e931f4d3c138d3

so I modified the widget similarly on lines 30:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0f7f7a559b5cd17cec8e

Now the widget displays both rule based related products and random products from different categories. I know the target rule is setup correctly as the correct items display in the normal related products block, but not the widget as described above.

Anyone have thoughts on how to modify the widget to work properly?

Comment: When creating the Rule, Which `Apply To` did you chose? Also check your conditions for `Products to Display`.

Comment: Sorry, I think you are understanding my question as I may not have been clear enough. There is no issue with the rule based relations themselves, they are working correctly. I am trying to get this widget to play nicely with them as currently the widget is only displaying manually related products. You can see the function that calls it into action above and I have outlined the files I've looked at to find the correct function for the rule base related products in abstract.php from the targetrule folder. But I can't seem to get it playing nicely.